# Update existing feed records using JAVA AdWords API

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I want to update existing feed records using `JAVA AdWords API`.

I tried but I am getting this error `FeedError.DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME`
I want to make changes in **SAME** Feed.

Is this even possible?

**Code Link:**
https://www.dropbox.com/home/my%20folder?preview=AddSiteLinksUsingFeeds.java

**Error:**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/Shoaib/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.2/guice-4.2.2.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[03 Oct 2019 03:17:59,332-requestInfoLogger:WARN:main] Request made: Service: FeedService Method: mutate clientCustomerId: 209-376-1609 URL: https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809/FeedService Request ID: 000593fee235f2a202ab42d7be091ca3 ResponseTime(ms): 147 OperationsCount: 0 IsFault: true FaultMessage: ApiException{applicationExceptionType=ApiException, errors=[FeedError{apiErrorType=FeedError, errorString=FeedError.DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME, fieldPath=operations[0].operand.name, fieldPathElements=[FieldPathElement{field=operations, index=0}, FieldPathElement{field=operand}, FieldPathElement{field=name}], reason=DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME, trigger=Feed test 7.6}]}
[03 Oct 2019 03:17:59,371-soapXmlLogger:INFO:main] SOAP request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <soapenv:Header>

        <ns1:RequestHeader xmlns:ns1="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">

            <ns1:clientCustomerId>209-376-1609</ns1:clientCustomerId>

            <ns1:developerToken>REDACTED</ns1:developerToken>

            <ns1:userAgent>unknown (AwApi-Java, AdWords-Axis/4.7.0, Common-Java/4.7.0, Axis/1.4, Java/12, maven)</ns1:userAgent>

            <ns1:validateOnly>false</ns1:validateOnly>

            <ns1:partialFailure>false</ns1:partialFailure>

        </ns1:RequestHeader>

    </soapenv:Header>

    <soapenv:Body>

        <mutate xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809">

            <operations>

                <operator>ADD</operator>

                <operand>

                    <name>Feed test 7.6</name>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Listing ID</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Listing Name</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Final URL</name>

                        <type>URL_LIST</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Image URL</name>

                        <type>URL</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>City name</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Description</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Price</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Property type</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Listing type</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Contextual keywords</name>

                        <type>STRING_LIST</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <attributes>

                        <name>Address</name>

                        <type>STRING</type>

                    </attributes>

                    <origin>USER</origin>

                </operand>

            </operations>

        </mutate>

    </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>

[03 Oct 2019 03:17:59,371-soapXmlLogger:INFO:main] SOAP response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <ResponseHeader xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809">
            <requestId>000593fee235f2a202ab42d7be091ca3</requestId>
            <serviceName>FeedService</serviceName>
            <methodName>mutate</methodName>
            <operations>0</operations>
            <responseTime>147</responseTime>
        </ResponseHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>[FeedError.DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME @ operations[0].operand.name; trigger:'Feed test 7.6']</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ApiExceptionFault xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809">
                    <message>[FeedError.DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME @ operations[0].operand.name; trigger:'Feed test 7.6']</message>
                    <ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type>
                    <errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="FeedError">
                        <fieldPath>operations[0].operand.name</fieldPath>
                        <fieldPathElements>
                            <field>operations</field>
                            <index>0</index>
                        </fieldPathElements>
                        <fieldPathElements>
                            <field>operand</field>
                        </fieldPathElements>
                        <fieldPathElements>
                            <field>name</field>
                        </fieldPathElements>
                        <trigger>Feed test 7.6</trigger>
                        <errorString>FeedError.DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME</errorString>
                        <ApiError.Type>FeedError</ApiError.Type>
                        <reason>DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME</reason>
                    </errors>
                </ApiExceptionFault>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Request failed due to ApiException. Underlying ApiErrors:
  Error 0: FeedError{apiErrorType=FeedError, errorString=FeedError.DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME, fieldPath=operations[0].operand.name, fieldPathElements=[FieldPathElement{field=operations, index=0}, FieldPathElement{field=operand}, FieldPathElement{field=name}], reason=DUPLICATE_FEED_NAME, trigger=Feed test 7.6}
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried. If it is java code and you are getting an error, please also post the entire error message. If you also got a stack trace, then please post that too. Note that you can [edit] your question and add these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify an existing feed, you'll need to use the `SET` operator insteand of `ADD` and provide the [feed ID](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/FeedService.Feed.html#id_1) of the feed.